# Hadoop client not able to connect to server

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I set up a 2-node Hadoop cluster, and running start-df.sh and start-yarn.sh works nicely (i.e. all expected services are running, no errors in the logs).

However, when I actually try to run an application, several tasks fail:

> 15/04/01 15:27:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id :
>   attempt_1427894767376_0001_m_000008_2, Status : FAILED

I checked the yarn and datanode logs, but nothing is reported there. 
In the userlogs, the syslogs files on the slave node all contain the following error message:

> 2015-04-01 15:27:21,077 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client:
>   Retrying connect to server:
>   slave.domain.be./127.0.1.1:53834. Already tried 9 time(s);
>   retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10,
>   sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS) 
>   2015-04-01 15:27:21,078 WARN [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: 
>   Exception running child :
>   java.net.ConnectException: Call From
>   slave.domain.be./127.0.1.1 to
>   slave.domain.be.:53834 failed on connection exception:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: 
>   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

So the problem is that the slave cannot connect to itself..

I checked whether there is a process running on the slave node listening at port 53834, but there is none.
However, all 'expected' ports are being listened on (50020,50075,..). Nowhere in my configuration I have used port 53834. It's always a different port on different runs.

Any ideas on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your error might be due to `loopback` address in your hosts file. Go to `/etc/hosts` file and comment the line with `127.0.1.1` in your slave nodes and master node(if necessary). Now start the hadoop processes.

**EDITED:**

1. Do this in terminal to edit `hosts` file without root permission:
   `sudo bash`
2. Enter your current user password to enter into root login. You can now edit your hosts file using:
   `nano /etc/hosts`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I should have mentioned that I do not have root access and cannot edit /etc/hosts

Comment: Updated answer. Look into it.